# What's wrong here in the proof of Doob-Dynkin Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

See the following proof of Doob-Dynkin Lemma.

---

**Doob-Dynkin Lemma:** Let $X,Y:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be random variables. Then $\sigma(Y)\subseteq\sigma(X)$ implies there exists a $\mathcal{B}/\mathcal{B}$-measurable function $f$ such that $f\circ X=Y$.

**Lemma:** Doob-Dynkin Lemma holds when $Y$ is a linear combination of disjoint indicator functions in $\mathbb R$. Formally, $$Y=\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i\textbf 1_{A_i}$$ where $\lambda_i\in\mathbb R$ and $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for any $i,j\in I$ with $i\not=j$.

**Proof of Lemma:**   Without loss of generality, we assume all $\lambda_i$ are pairwise distinct. Let $A= \{A_i:i\in I\}$, then we have $\sigma(Y)=\sigma(A)\subseteq\sigma(X)$. That means there is a collection $B=\{B_i:i\in I\}$ such that $X^{-1}(B_i)=A_i$ for $i\in I$, and $f=\sum\limits_{i\in I} \lambda_i\textbf 1_{B_i}$ will suffice.

**Proof of Doob-Dynkin Lemma:** As every mapping $Y:S\rightarrow\mathbb R$ can be written as
$$Y=\sum_{v\in\mathbb R}v\textbf{1}_{A_v}$$
where $A_v=\{s\in S:f(s)=v\}$ . By Lemma 1, the Doob-Dynkin Lemma holds.

---

I cannot see any wrong in this proof.

I also search for the common proof of Doob-Dynkin Lemma, and they always divide $Y$ into $Y^+-Y^-$. But I don't know why we should do that. Is there any necessity to let $Y=Y^+-Y^-$. What' s the difference between them?

I would be very grateful for the answer.

Comment: It is the common technique that called standard machinery. (1) Prove the statement is true for indicator functions;

(2) Use linearity to prove it for all simple functions;

(3) Use simple to appxomiate all the non-negative function;

(4) For general function $X$, use $X=X^+-X^-$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069667/standard-machine-in-measure-theory

Answer (score 2):

Your so-called proof makes no sense at all. Are you saying that any real valued function (not even mentioning measurabiluty) is  a simple function for which the Lemma can be apllied? The lemma applies only to **finite** sums where the sets $A_i$ belong to the given sigma algebra. When you apply this lemma you have to make sure that the hypothesis of the lemma is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still confused about two things: first, I cannot see why that Lemma only applies to finite sum? When Ai are infinite, Bi are also infinite, but that f seems to be still well-defined. Will that make anything wrong? Second, why are the measurability of X and Y important? I believe "sigma(Y) is a subset of sigma(X)" is enough, and we don't care about the sigma-algebra at all. Thanks a lot as I'm just a newbie.

Comment: I understand a little bit. Is it because the infinite sum will make f not measurable, so the lemma only applies to finite sum?