# Definition of a finite vector-valued Radon measure: isn't this condition vacuous?

Tags: measure-theory, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, borel-measures, vector-measure

In [Diestel & Uhl's "Vector measures"](https://www.ams.org/books/surv/015/surv015-endmatter.pdf) one finds the following definition 1 on page 1.

**Definition 1 (Countably additive vector measure).**
Let $X$ be a [Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space) an $\mathcal F$ a [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) on a set $\Omega$. A function $F \colon \mathcal F \to X$ is a countably additive [vector measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_measure) if $F\left(\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_n\right) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} F(E_n)$ in the norm topology of $X$ for all pairwise disjoint sequences $(E_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathcal F$ with $\bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_n \in \mathcal F$.

In [Yann Brenier & Dimitry Vorotnikov's "On optimal transport of matrix-valued measures"](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/19M1274857), they define $\mathbb P^+$ to be "the set of $\mathcal P^+$-valued Radon measures $P$ on $\mathbb R^d$ with finite [$\text{tr}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra))$(\text{d}P(\mathbb R^d))$", where $\mathcal P^+$ is the subspace of  real $d \times d$ [symmetric positive semidefinite matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix)".

The notation $dP$ is explained in the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618076/545914).
They don't define what "Radon" means in the context of vector valued measures, but I assume that it means [some kind regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_measure#Definitions) (with respect to the [Loewner order on the symmetric matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order)?).

### My Question

If $P \in \mathbb P^+$, doesn't that mean that $P$ maps from $\Sigma$ into $\mathcal P^+$, where $\Sigma$ is some $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^d$?
Because $\text{tr}(A) < \infty$ for all $A \in \mathcal P^+$ and  $P(E) \in \mathcal P^+$ for every $E \in \Sigma$ and wouldn't we have in particular $\text{tr}(P(\mathbb R^d)) < \infty$?

In particular if $d = 1$, would the [one-dimensional Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) not belong to $\mathbb P^+$?

**Question 2.**
Is there some way to find out from the paper what they mean by Radon?
I only found out that in subsection 2.2. of the paper [Matrix Measures and Finite Rank Perturbations of Self-adjoint Operators by Constanze Liaw and Sergei Treil](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.08856), Radon measures (on $\mathbb R$) are countably additive set function defined on bounded Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$, which are bounded on bounded Borel subsets.

---

I have a similar issue with a similar definition in [Léonard Monsaingeon & Dmitry Vorotnikov's "The Schrödinger problem on the non-commutative
Fisher-Rao space"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00526-020-01871-w.pdf): they define a TV norm of a $H$-valued Radon measure on p. 14 (where $H$ are the Hermitian $d \times d$ matrices) and then $\mathbb H$ as the set of $H$-valued Radon measures with finite [TV norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_norm_of_vector-valued_measures). But a norm on a set should always be finite, so why isn't this condition vacuous as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted on of the authors and they said that Radon in this case means that every entry is a Radon measure in the usual sense. In this case the finite trace condition is not vacuous, for example for $d = 1$ the usual Lebesgue measure does not fulfill the finite trace condition.